# Excel VBA Inserting Worksheet_Change Code Into Multiple Worksheets

Tags: vba, excel

What would be the  approach for a macro that places a Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) worksheet into the worksheet modules of 20 identical worksheets in a workbook that has 25 worksheets?

Answer (score 2):

Change to a Workbook_SheetChange and use the *Sh* argument to determine the worksheet receiving the changes.

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)
     select case sh.name
          case "Sheet1", "Sheet2", "Sheet3"
              'do something
          case else
              'do nothing
     end select
End Sub
```

Comment: Does this go in the ThisWorkbook module? I get a compile error on "Me.UsedRange" . Do I need to add the Sh argument to the code?

Comment: Yes, exactly as I stated above. *Sh* is the worksheet object so `sh.usedrange`, etc. or `With Sh ... End With`. See above how I used `sh.name` like `me.name`?